# Multiboot options in Windows 10

Tags: boot

When booting, my Win-10 PC offers a list of 6 partitions to [supposedly] boot from but actually only two partitions contain WIN-10 operating systems. Is there a way to eliminate the unwanted "boot options" to leave only the two OSs?

Thanks

Comment: Please verify that the other 4 partitions are not OEM or recovery partitions. My win7 installation has 4 partitions: OEM, a Windows Recovery Partition, Windows(C: drive), and an OEM recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would be careful when editing the boot configuration. Definitely create a backup before you change anything.

I think I found an article that will help you get rid of your extra entries. Check this out and let me know if it helps. Towards the end it shows how to remove entries.

[MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-boot-entries)

Comment: I have read the article and it seems to fit my needs. I'll study the instructions carefully and definitely respond regarding the results.

Comment: I followed the instructions. After each item deleted - I rebooted to test the results. After removing the third option on the list the pc did not boot. I had to apply the fixboot procedures with the Windows 10 installation pendrive. After reconstructing the Boot menu - all 6 options returned as nothing happened. It seems that I'll just have to get used to the abnormality... Thanks friends...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Graphical BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/) for easy editing of BCD store.

1. Start tool.

On the left side of program under "Loaders" you will see a list of loaders.

2. Click on loader you want to delete, then right click and select "Delete".
3. Repeat (2.) on every loader you want to get rid of.

WARNING: You should be careful what you delete as there is NO UNDO!

Before starting deletion you can "Backup BCD" to a file (if you make a mistake just "Restore BCD" from the saved file.)